# Windows docker desktop how to add an entry point or command

Tags: docker

[image]

I want to run a container with an entry command of '/bin/bash' in above the windows docker desktop , just like as if I run "docker run -it <image_name> /bin/bash" from command line.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can spin up the container from Docker Desktop. Then find out the container ID using `docker ps` and enter the container like so: `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash` if that's what you desire.

However, ENTRYPOINT is a property of a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). You can't work with it via the DD UI.